# Can't edit comments?

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, edits, moderator-tools

On the site where I moderate, the edit buttons on comments, both my own and others', have disappeared:

[image]

(However, I still seem to be able to edit my own new comments on sites where I'm not a moderator.)

A problem with the mod tools?

Comment: The edit link is still there on the mobile web interface, so you can use that as a workaround for now.

Comment: @snailboat I'm old-fashioned; my mobile does nothing but calls and texts. If it doesn't work on a computer, it doesn't work for me. (But +1 to your comment so that others see it.)

Comment: I'm looking at this now.

Comment: You can also edit the HTML of the page to change `<a class="comment-edit comment-edit-hide">edit</a>` of the comment you want to edit to `<a class="comment-edit">edit</a>` as a temporary workaround.

Comment: (And even on a computer, you can click the "mobile" link in the footer to get the mobile web interface)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found the problem - some CSS got lost in a move, I found the missing bits, put them back in place and all should be back to normal.

This is being deployed right now - expect things to be right in about 5 minutes.

Comment: "Missing bits" haha, clever (whether intended or not).

Comment: Great, thanks! Appreciate the speed with which you can fix this stuff :-)

Comment: It is happening to me again on the latest version of Chrome on Ubuntu 16.04